# NullInjectorError: No provider for AddItemPage! -- Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, runtime-error, angular5

Error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[AddItemPage]:
>   StaticInjectorError[AddItemPage]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for AddItemPage! Error: StaticInjectorError[AddItemPage]:    StaticInjectorError[AddItemPage]:
>
> ```
> NullInjectorError: No provider for AddItemPage!
> at _NullInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1276:19)
> at resolveToken (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1564:24)
> at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1506:16)
> at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1377:20)
> at resolveToken (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1564:24)
> at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1506:16)
> at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1377:20)
> at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:10938:25)
> at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12159:16)
> at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:10938:25)
> at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
> at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19174)
> at NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:48310:16)
> at NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:48303:14)
> at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:48350:59
> at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
> at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4982:33)
> at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
> at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
> at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
> ```

When I write in HomePage:

```
import { AddItemPage } from './../add-item/add-item';
...
constructor(... ,private addItemPage: AddItemPage){...}
...
editItems(item){
    this.addItemPage.editItem(item);
}
```

So I want to **call a methode** from **AddItemPage** in **HomePage**.
Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Add import to **app.module.ts**

```
...
import { AddItemPage } from '../add-item/add-item';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    AddItemPage 
  ],
...
```

Comment: Is `AddItemPage` component, page, provider or something else? https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/generate/

Answer (score 0):

You're calling AddItemPage like a provider. So if AddItemPage is a page, you need to import it into app.module.ts declaration array.
Then, you want to call a method from AddItemPage in HomePage. To get access to a component and its methods, you can use the @ViewChild decorator.

```
export class AddItemPage {
  constructor() {}
  doSomething() {
    //send data
  }
}


import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AddItemPage } from '../add-item';

export class HomePage {
  // ViewChild takes a class type or a reference name string.
  // Here we are using the type
  @ViewChild(AddItemPage) addItemPage: AddItemPage

  constructor() { }

  update() {
    this.addItemPage.doSomething();
  }
}
```

I do not know what the goal is, but I think you can do it differently.
Hope I help!